# Set a different timeout to each selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

I am currently adding a class name "animate" to `<li>` items with this script:

```
$('.list-blocks li').addClass('animate');
```

But this script immediately sets the class to the selected elements.

How can I add the class to the next selected element with one second buffer?

For example: After the page is loaded, the script give the first `li` the class "animate". After 1 second, the second `li` get the class "animate". And after 2 seconds the third `li` gets the class "animate".

How can I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.list-blocks li').each(function (index) {
  var item = $(this);
  setTimeout(function () {
    item.addClass('animate');
  }, index * 1000);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bKaUV/)

Answer (score 4):

Loop over all elements and set a timeout.

```
$('.list-blocks li').each(function(index, elm) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(elm).addClass('animate');
    }, index*1000);
});
```

should work. See http://api.jquery.com/each/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: This is not working. The elm.addClass is not Object #<HTMLLIElement> has no method 'addClass'

Comment: `setTimeout(function() { elm.addClass('animate') }, index*1000);`

Comment: sorry, forgot to jqueryfy. Thanks for the update dfsq and thanks for editing, @Yoshi.